# How to prevent API calls on a minute timer loop when in the process of logging out of a web app?

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, rxjs

In my Ionic/Angular app, I have a 60 second timer observable which just emits the current time synced with server time. Each minute I fetch permissions, settings, etc. I pass a token with each request. On logout I revoke the token. Here's a sample of what my logic looks like.

Side note: There's also a feature where a user can "change login type" where they can "become" an administrator, for example, and this process may also trigger a similar circumstance.

```
this.clientTimeSub = this.timeService.clientTime
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.logoutService.isLoggingOut$))
      .subscribe(async (latestClientTime) => {
          this.clientTime = { ...latestClientTime };
          // if client time just rolled over to a new minute, update settings
          if (
            this.clientTime?.time?.length === 7 &&
            this.clientTime?.time?.slice(-1) === '0'
          ) {
            await updateSettings();
            await updatePermissions();
            // etc

            // These functions will:
            // (1) make an api call (using the login token!)
            // (2) update app state
            // (3) save to app storage

          }
      });
```

When I am logging out of the app, there's a small time window where I could be in the middle of sending multiple api requests and the token is no longer valid, due to the timer rolling to a new minute just as I was logging out, or close to it. I am then presented with a 401: Unauthorized in the middle of logging out.

My naive solution was to tell this observable to stop propagation when a Subject or BehaviorSubject fires a value telling this observable that it is logging out, you can see this here `.pipe(takeUntil(this.logoutService.isLoggingOut$))`.

Then, in any of my logout methods, I would use:

```
logout() {
  this.isLoggingOut.next(true);
  
  ...
  // Logout logic here, token becomes invalidated somewhere here
  // then token is deleted from state, etc, navigate back to login...
  ...
  
 this.isLoggingOut.next(false);
}
```

In that small time window of logging out, the client timer should stop firing and checking if it's rolled to a new minute, preventing any further api calls that may be unauthenticated.

Is there a way I can easily prevent this issue from happening or is there a flaw in my logic that may be causing this issue?

I appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is not the best way to use async-await along with RXJS. Its because RXJS as a reactive way of functional programming, have its "pipeable" operators so you can kinda "chain" everything.

So instead of having a logic of calculating time in your subscribe callback function you should rather use, for example **filter**() RXJ operator, and instead of using await-async you can use **switchMap** operator and inside it, use **forkJoin** or concat operator.

```
this.timeService.clientTime
  .pipe(
    // Filter stream (according to your calculation)
    filter((time) => {
      // here is your logic to calculate if time has passed or whatever else you are doing
      // const isValid = ...
      return isValid;
    }),
    // Switch to another stream so you can call api calls
    // Here with "from" we are converting promises to observables in order to be able to use magic of RXJS
    switchMap(_ => forkJoin([from(updateSettings), from(updatePermissions)])),
    // Take until your logout
    takeUntil(this.logoutService.isLoggingOut$)
  ).subcribe(([updateSettings, updatePermissions]) => {
    
   // Basically your promises should just call API services, and other logic should be here
    
  // Here you can use
  // (2) update app state
  // (3) save to app storage
})
```

If you split actions like in my example, in your promises you just call api calls to update whatever you are doing, then when its done, in subscribe callback you can update app state, save to app storage etc. So you can have 2 scenarios here:

1. Api calls from promises, are still in progress. If you trigger logout in the meanwhile **takeUntil** will do the thing and you will not update app state etc.
2. If both Api calls from promises are done, you are in a subscribe callback block and if its just a synchronous code (hopefully) it will be done. And then async code can be executed (your timer can now emit next value, its all about Event Loop in javascript)

Comment: I appreciate the response, I think it makes sense. I just have a question, so if I'm in the process of logging out, but I'm already in the middle of the chain to make api calls to updateSettings/updatePermissions, does the RxJS chain stop in the middle of processing?

Comment: Calling api is an async call. For example, it will last for 5seconds (lets say for both promises). I put forkJoin to call it in parallel.

Let say that after 2 seconds you trigger logout. Logout will emit a value and it will come to takeUntil operator. At that point chain is "stopped". You will not get a value in a subscribe callback block anymore. That means that when api calls are done, subscribe callback will not be executed because chain is "stopped"...

Comment: Ok that makes sense, this seems like better practice than what I have got going in my app. But the issue I think will still exist in your answer due to logout being called (which invalidates the auth token) and (possibly milliseconds later) still be in the process of fetching settings which then triggers a 401 Unauthorized due to using the same token that just became invalid. This is the main issue I'm trying to solve, if that makes sense. And maybe your solution solves my problem, I'm not sure, but even if it doesn't I will try to change my chaining to include API calls with forkJoin

Comment: Its kinda hard to debug your scenario because you post only a limited chunk of your code. Its hard to tell what is in happening your case because i am not sure which part of your code (logout, update state etc) is a synchronous and which one is async. The point is, if API calls are already triggered, and in the meanwhile (before they get back from the server) you call logout function (in that function at the begining you call this.isLoggingOut.next(true); or whatever) that will automatically end pipable chain due takeUntil operator. If logout occurs before api calls,then it will just end chain

Comment: But, you can have a problem with a race condition, if reading auth token (from local storage i guess) is wrapped to be a async function. If my solution does not work, you should take a look where do you have async operations in the code that you did not post here

Comment: Right! a race condition is exactly what's happening... I think it's just all related to having a logout api endpoint which is async, which is called during the logout method, to tell the server to clear the token which to me is bad practice

Comment: Went through the process of updating my RxJS subscriptions using some of your logic and everything is working perfectly now. It totally makes sense to me now.